# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist when querying in Python

Tags: python, oracle

I got this error when querying Oracle data from Python, with the query below:

```
CONN_INFO = {
    'host': '192.xxx.xxx.xx',
    'port': 4445,
    'user': 'User27',
    'psw': '12345678',
    'service': 'xxxxxxx.xxxx.com',
}

CONN_STR = '{user}/{psw}@{host}:{port}/{service}'.format(**CONN_INFO)

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(CONN_STR)

query = """
select * from EM.df

 """
df = pd.read_sql(query, con=connection)
df
```

the error looks like this:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
select * from EM.Sales

 ': ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

However, I have verified that table 'df' does exist and that the select query runs fine within Oracle DB. What could be the reasons why this happened?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I think it's not specific to VSC, what I mean is when queried in Python

Comment: Your code shows the table as 'em.df' and you say you have verified you have 'df'. 
However the error shows the query against 'em.sales' failing.  Check you are running the correct code, and there is no other place in the application that is querying 'em.sales'.  Check you can access 'em.df', not just 'df'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You log on as the user `User27` and then you query the table `EM.df` (or maybe `EM.Sales`, as that is mentioned in the error message) which means you are querying the `df` table owned by the `EM` user.

> I have verified that table 'df' does exist and that the select query runs fine within Oracle DB.

You need to check that:

1. The table `df` exists for the `EM` user, and not for `User27` (otherwise the table will exist but for the wrong user).
2. That `User27` has been granted the `SELECT` privilege on `EM.df` (otherwise the table will exist but the user you are connecting as will not be able to see it).